# Get current month in groovy jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Currently, I have a declarative pipeline setup as:

```
def monthToBool() {
   if (env.CURRENT_MONTH == '0' || env.CURRENT_MONTH == '3' || env.CURRENT_MONTH == '6' || env.CURRENT_MONTH == '9') {
        return true
   } else {
        return false
   }
}

pipeline {
   environment {
      ...
      CURRENT_MONTH = new Date().getMonth()
      CURRENT_MONTH_BOOL = monthToBool()

   }

   stages {
       stage('stage1') {...}
       stage('stage2') {...}
   }

}
```

The Date().getMonth() method returns 0-11, where 0 is January and 11 is December, so it is indexed starting at 0. But for some reason, the monthToBool() method is always returning false, even though CURRENT_MONTH returns 9, is that because of a typing issue or something?

Comment: It's probably setting it as an integer, not a String... Try `CURRENT_MONTH = "${new Date().getMonth()}"` However, it should be noted that `getMonth()` has been deprecated for about 20 years, and the "modern" (post Java 8) way of doing it is: `LocalDate.now().monthValue` which returns 1 for January, or 10 for October

Comment: I also just used Date().format('MM'), which returned 10, is this also working as a String and not deprecated?

Comment: To your LocalDate suggestion, would it be CURRENT_MONTH = new LocalDate.now().monthValue? or monthValue() or getMonthValue()?
Also I saw the documentation, and it seems its retuning an int?

Comment: I tried the ```CURRENT_MONTH = "${new Date().getMonth()}"```, but it's still setting the method as false

Comment: Try `CURRENT_MONTH = new Date().getMonth() as String` to exclude type mismatch.

Comment: Also could you show where you are calling `monthToBool()`. Could you println the env variable in it?

Comment: yeah i just added the edit, its just another value under the CURRENT_MONTH as CURRENT_MONTH_BOOL

Comment: Also what do you mean by try ```CURRENT_MONTH = new Date().getMonth() as String```? Isn't that what I did initially?

Comment: i've even tried newDate().getMonth().toString() and that still returned 9, so is my method not working or something because its just giving me false?

Comment: you could identify a type mismatch by just throwing a `println env.CURRENT_MONTH.getClass()` in there.